# What do these sums converge to?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\left \{ z_n \right \}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}$$ Show that it converges and determine the value it converges to.

**Attempt**

Think I would have to write the sum as $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+(k/n)}\frac{1}{n}$$

Then to argue that it converges I would use the integral test with the bounds $a=1$ and $b=\infty$ but this is just what I think I know. How do I evalute the sum?

Comment: Instead of "integral test" I would try "Riemann sum".

Comment: @GEdgar I have worked out the integral to be a finite value i.e $\log(2)$, now this is where I am struggeling a bit. Is this sufficient for arguing for convergence and finding the value?

Comment: I would echo @GEdgar loudly: This has nothing to do with the "integral test".

Comment: @zhw. I realized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+k/n} = \int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}dx$$

---

For convergence, we note that this satisfies the Cauchy's criterion:
$$|z_{n+p} - z_n| = \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} \frac{1}{n+k}\right| \le \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{1}{n+n+1} = \frac{p}{2n+1} \to 0$$

Comment: I have worked it out to be a finite value i.e $\log(2)$, now this is where I am struggeling a bit. Is this sufficient for arguing for convergence and finding the value?

Comment: @mathstudent23 No, that is not enough, see the edit.

Comment: 1 clarification. I am not sure on where you get the $m$ from in your index? Would the criterion normally just be $|z_m-z_n|$?

Comment: @mathstudent23 Sorry, that $m$ was a typo. Yes normally $|z_n-z_m|$ but since they are natural numbers they can be written in relation $m = n+p$.

Comment: but then $|z_m-z_n|$ and not $|z_n-z_m|$, right? But then the last term should look different for the fraction if I am understanding it correctly?

Comment: @mathstudent23 Note that $|a-b| = |b-a|$.

Comment: My mistake. But regarding the last term; that tends to $0$ since $n$ goes to $\infty$, right?

Comment: isn't the first sum in the Cauchy criterion wrong? Having a bit og trouble seeing how that is that sum.

Comment: There is no need to go through the Cauchy business if we know the limit in your hint equals $\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{1+x}\,dx.$

Comment: @zhw. Yes, that was just for those who are interested in only convergence.